# saving random picture on the computer / ip

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a script that draws a random picture after pressing the button.

```
var imagesArray = ["slonce.gif", "gwiazda.gif", "kochankowie.gif", "wieza.gif"];

function displayImage(){
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); // 0...6
    document.picture.src = imagesArray[num];

}
```

I want the picture to be remembered for the whole day on the computer or IP that randomized it.
I read about local storage and cookies but I have no idea how I can set the lifetime of this choice.

I created something this and it works

```
function createCookie(cookieName,cookieValue)
    {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+(1*24*60*60*1000));
      document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + cookieValue + "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
function getCookie(cookieName)
    {
      var name = cookieName + "=";
      var allCookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
      for(var i=0; i<allCookieArray.length; i++)
      {
        var temp = allCookieArray[i].trim();
        if (temp.indexOf(name)==0)
        return temp.substring(name.length,temp.length);
       }
      return "";
    }
function checkCookie()
    {
      var number = getCookie("randomPicture");
      if (number!=""){
        document.picture.src = imagesArray[number];
      }
      else
      {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4); // 0...3
        document.picture.src = imagesArray[num];
        if (num!=null)
        {
        createCookie("randomPicture", num);
        }
      }
    }
```

called with the function checkCookie()

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far so we can try to help you fix your problems.

Comment: You can't specify an expiration for localStorage - I think your best bet for a localStorage solution would be storing a timestamp and checking against that when the User loads the page / runs displayImage() again

Answer (score 0):

One *simple* option that you have, would be to store a cookie on the computer which expires after one day. Then, at the time the page is loaded you can use JavaScript to check if the cookie is there.

If it is, then you can show the button, otherwise show the picture.

[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) covers how to store a cookie and provides a function:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  var d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
  var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

They also have written a function get a cookie:

```
function getCookie(cname) {
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```